# Dynamic Arrays in C++ (Array of pointers or new array?)

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, heap-memory, allocation

If I want to create an dynamic array of objects:

I can create an array using the new keyword where C++ will automatically create an array of node objects and call the default constructor for all nodes.

```
node* nodes = new node[10];
```

Or I can create an array of pointers to nodes and instantiate the nodes individually.

```
node* nodes[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    nodes[i] = new node();
}
```

When would it be appropriate to use either? In the first example, are the nodes still dynamically allocated when using the new keyword with an array?

Many thanks!

Comment: Whenever I hair "dynamic array" I always think [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: The first example default-initializes them and the second (which, still using pointers, should be `std::fill`) value-initializes them.

Comment: I'll leave the answer to someone else, but the difference in when you use one approach or the other depends on how you want to deallocate the objects. With the first, you have to deallocate all of the objects at once. With the second, you can deallocate them one at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between these two code snippets there is a big difference.

In the second case that is when the following definition is used

```
node* nodes[10];
```

you can not add new elements to the array. The array has fixed size.

In the first case when you use operator new for the whole array

```
node* nodes = new node[10];
```

the array can be reallocated with an arbitrary number of elements.

So the main criteria is whether you need an array of fixed size or not, whether the underlying class has a default constructor or not.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in how they are created except for the fact that the first expression is used to allocate memory to contain one single element of type `node`. The second one is used to allocate a block (an array) of elements of type `node`. Creating a dynamic array of objects dynamically allocates each object regardless of the way you create them. The only difference obviously here between the two is whether or not you actually need to do something else with the newly created node individually or not.

Answer (score -1):

```
       For **Dynamic Allocation** we can use Vector in C++

     int main()
        {

        vector<int> v1;
        int x;


        for(int j=0;j<=3;j++)
        {
        cin>>x;
        v1.push_back(x);// Here we pushing 4 values to the Vector..
        }
        v1.push_back(12);//Adding one more value to Vector dynamically
for(int i=0;i<v1.size();i++){

cout<<v1[i]<<"";
}

        }
```

Comment: What i did? I was just telling you can also try this approach

Comment: The question was: I have this two methods, which one is better and why? Your answer: Try this other method.